# How to find out if a nuget Package is usable in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

If i search a nuget package within visual studio or at https://www.nuget.org/, how do i see if the nuget package is usable in .net core?

As far as I know, there is currently no possibility to search directly for nuget packages which can be used in .net core ([Source](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3098)). But can i check it for a specific one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to search for packages by target-framework.

You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3098) on Github for news/more information